# Regex to filter out double period in email address

Tags: regex, email

Currently I have the regex below, I have been trying to implement a change to accommodate for failing any emails that have a double period before the @ such as:

1. `Chris..Louis@gmail.com` <- fail
2. `Chris.Louis@gmail.com` <- pass
3. `Chris.Louis.@gmail.com` <- fail
4. `Chris.Louis.Stack@gmail.com` <- pass

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\)\\-`.+,~?{|}=*%\"]*[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\)\\-`+,~?{|}=*%\"]+[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\)\\- 
    `+,~?{|}=*%\"]*[@][a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\)\\-`.+,~?{|}=*%\"]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the negative lookahead `(?![^@]*\.\.)` to the start of your pattern:

```
^(?![^@]*\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\)\-.+,~?{|}=*%\"]*[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\)\\-+,~?{|}=%"]+[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\)\- +,~?{|}=*%\"]*[@][a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\)\\-.+,~?{|}=%"]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
   ^^^ change is here
```

The lookahead added above will fail if it finds double dot anywhere before a `@` symbol appears.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works. I ended up adding the negative lookahead to each portion of it as put below.
'''
"(^(?![^@]*\\.\\.)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\/)\\-`.+,~?{|}=*%\"]*(?![^@]*\\.\\.)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\/)\\-`+,~?{|}=*%\"]+(?![^@]*\\.\\.)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\/)\\-`+,~?{|}=*%\"]*[@](?![^@]*\\.\\.)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&(\\/)\\-`.+,~?{|}=*%\"]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,6}$)") 

'''